# Applying subtraction to each row in rdd - PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This code creates an rdd of ints and prints them :

```
schema = StructType([StructField('value', IntegerType(), False)])
rdd = sc.parallelize([[100],[50],[25]])
myrdd = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema).rdd
for x in myrdd.collect():
    print(x)
```

prints :

```
Row(value=100)
Row(value=50)
Row(value=25)
```

I'm attempting to subtract a value from this `rdd` so that with each subtraction if there is a remainder it is subtracted from next row.

As an example to subtract 125 take 100 from the first row and 25 from the second row which will leave a new rdd of value :

```
Row(value=0)
Row(value=25)
Row(value=25)
```

As a further example to subtract 160 take 100 from the first row , 50 from the second row and 10 from third row which will leave a new rdd of value :

```
Row(value=0)
Row(value=0)
Row(value=15)
```

My attempt:

```
valueToRemove = 125
def myFun(s):
    valueToRemove = valueToRemove - s['value']
    return Row(value = valueToRemove)

myrdd1 = myrdd.map(myFun)

for x in myrdd1.collect():
    print(x)
```

Which causes error :

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'valueToRemove' referenced before assignment
```

I think a natural solution for this is a `foldLeft` but `foldLeft` is not supported in Apache spark. Also I cannot use `fold` as the rows are to be processed in deterministic order.

How to subtract a value from each row and store the result of the subtraction to be used in next row ?

Update :

Adding global :

```
schema = StructType([StructField('value', IntegerType(), False)])
rdd = sc.parallelize([[100],[50],[25]])
myrdd = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema).rdd
for x in myrdd.collect():
    print(x)

global valueToRemove
valueToRemove = 125

def myFun(s):
    valueToRemove = valueToRemove - s['value']
    return Row(value = valueToRemove)

myrdd1 = myrdd.map(myFun)

for x in myrdd1.collect():
    print(x)
```

results in same error.

Comment: this is bad form, but does adding `global valueToRemove` work?

Comment: @user3080953 adding global results in same error, i've updated question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Assumptions

I solved it assuming:

1. The data can be left as DataFrame
2. There is a column indicating the row number of the value

With the above assumptions, this is my version of the input

```
schema = StructType([StructField('row', IntegerType(), 
False),StructField('value', IntegerType(), False)])
rdd = sc.parallelize([[1, 100],[2, 50],[3, 25],[4,225]])
myrdd = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
for x in myrdd.collect():
    print(x)
```

Prints:

```
Row(row=1, value=100)
Row(row=2, value=50)
Row(row=3, value=25)
Row(row=4, value=225)
```

---

### Solution

First Add a cumulative sum column:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

w = Window.orderBy("row")
tempDF = myrdd.select("value","row",F.sum("value").over(w).alias("cumsum"))

tempDF.show()
```

prints:

```
+-----+---+------+
|value|row|cumsum|
+-----+---+------+
|  100|  1|   100|
|   50|  2|   150|
|   25|  3|   175|
|  225|  4|   400|
+-----+---+------+
```

Last I defined a [UDF](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-in-python.html) to compute the new value:

```
def new_val(cumsum_val, row_val, target_val):
    if cumsum_val - row_val >= target_val:
        #rows that are after the "affected area"
        return row_val
    if cumsum_val - target_val < 0:
        # rows that use all their values
        return 0
    # rows with reminders
    return cumsum_val - target_val
new_val_udf = F.udf(new_val)
value = 160
tempDF.withColumn("new_val",new_val_udf(F.col("cumsum"), F.col("value"), F.lit(value))).show()
```

The output is:

```
+-----+---+------+-------+
|value|row|cumsum|new_val|
+-----+---+------+-------+
|  100|  1|   100|      0|
|   50|  2|   150|      0|
|   25|  3|   175|     15|
|  225|  4|   400|    225|
+-----+---+------+-------+
```